# What does it mean to create a function that "accepts a positive integer"?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, integer

I'm in the process of creating a program in Javascript that is telling me to:

"Create a function "sum" that accepts a positive integer, uses a FOR loop to compute the summation of 1 to that parameter, and then has the function return it".

I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me, I would like to be able to complete the assignment on my own, but the wording in the instructions given are sometimes hard to understand. Anyone able to help?

Comment: `if (parameter >= 0) { // positive integer }`

Comment: [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)... or in other words, it's a whole number that's not-negative

Comment: func(1), func(2) ... Should not throw an error

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that you do not have to support the case where a negative number is passed to the function.